# Open Telemetry not exporting to Jaeger

Tags: python, fastapi, open-telemetry, jaeger

I have open telemetry exporting traces to Jaeger for many Node.js services, however with python, its not working:

```
opentelemetry-instrument \  
    --traces_exporter console,otlp \
    --metrics_exporter console \
    --service_name llama-indexer \
    --exporter_otlp_protocol http/protobuf \
    --exporter_otlp_endpoint http://localhost:4318/v1/traces \
    start_api
```

The traces log with no issue to the console, but do not show up at all in jaeger

I have the same endpoint for js traces, works just fine. Heres my docker container in case it helps
`83bce0bb7a12   jaegertracing/all-in-one       "/go/bin/all-in-one-…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour          5775/udp, 5778/tcp, 14250/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4317-4318->4317-4318/tcp, 0.0.0.0:16686->16686/tcp, 6831-6832/udp, 14268/tcp   jaeger`

Is there any way to get better observability into whats going wrong with the exporter, or anything obvious im missing

I tried many different parameters, I tried directly sending traces to datadog (didn't work) I tried manually instrumenting the FastAPI.

I have also tried using GRPC exporter, and it works, but i need http.

Comment: This may be a bug, but for a start you'd have to extract a [mcve]. Then, if it turns out to be a bug, file a report in the software's bug tracker. Here, this seems rather off-topic, since you're not programming something but just using some software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with my `--exporter_otlp_endpoint` value. I used http://localhost:4318/v1/traces which was incorrect (although worked with grpc for some reason).

Switching to:

```py
--exporter_otlp_endpoint http://localhost:4318 \
```

solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your opentelemetry collector is in a Docker container. Then it might be due to missing some Docker networking resources.

For me it works with docker-compose, but not with `docker run ...`, because compose automatically has a more open local network.